# How to wait for tasks to be completed by GPars Agent class?

Tags: gpars

Currently I am using GPars Agent class to process typical shopping cart scenario. I have a situation where I need to wait for addtocart, minicart tasks to complete before viewcart task returns response. The webservice call returns viewcart before returning addtocart/minicart. How do I let Agent class know to process the viewcart after other tasks are completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agents always process submitted tasks sequentially. So if you submit the viewcart task last, it will be processed last.
You may call agent.await() of agent.val to block the caller until all so-far-submitted tasks have been completed.

Comment: Thank you. In my scenario, every request is a unique request. For instance, upon client request, first addTOCart is assigned to Agent and processed, so when we I click viewcart, Agent gets a new task instead of a List of tasks. So, agent.await() of agent.val, could find only viewcart in the Agent.val. Is there a good way to handle this situation?

Comment: I'm afraid I do not fully understand the issue. What do you mean by a List of tasks? Agents only accept a single task (a closure) at a time and process them in the order of submittion. The task submitted later will start after the tasks submitted before it finish.

Comment: Sorry. My issue is when I click addtocart button from UI, I consume webservice call and service returns Json to UI. Same applies for minicart, viewcart. Now, I added GPars Agent to the controller which contains addtocart, minicart and viewcart definitions/methods(Im using groovy). The Agent does pretty good job keeping the call asynchronous and thread safe. My issue here is each request from UI is a new request so Agent identifies only one task(addtocart or viewcart) per request. Hence, when I make the agent wait after addtocart, agent.val() and agent.await() doesnt find value to wait.

Comment: and I dont have control over the client request. The viewcart can send in request anytime or addtocart can send in request anytime. I just need to find a way to make agent wait if the addtocart clicked before viewcart. is this possible? Thanks alot for helping me.

Comment: I'm afraid prioritizing requests is something Agents will not do for you, just like any traditional shared data structure, such as a synchronized list, wouldn't. You'll have to implement the prioritization in the code around, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Vaclav Pech,

Thank you much. Appreciate your help. I have handled this scenario adding a counter before(increment counter) and after(decrement counter) the service and waiting for the items to be processed in the View cart and redirect them to viewcart page. Just wanted to add my answer to this thread.